# Am I right about the major differences between activity, service and broadcast in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I found Android's key components a little bit confusing, thus I have made a chart for me to remember. But I am not sure whether I am right or not. (It will be disastrous if I remember wrong things correct.) Thus I have decided to post a question on Stack Overflow to check.

```
item       | ____ground | runtime reg? | 1 to ?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
activity   | foreground | no           | 1 (multiple candidates for implicit, finally still 1)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
service    | background | no           | 1 (multiple candidates for implicit, finally still 1)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
broadcast  | background | yes          | all (may not reach all if aborted for ordered)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, yes.
See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components) in the android developer guide that explains pretty much what you established.

So you can rest easy now, you're right :)